# Глубокий проброс props в компоненты

Tags: reactjs

Допустим есть компонент, который включает в себя другой, который в свою очередь третий и так очень глубоко. Корневой компонент может содержать целую сложную иерархию компонентов. И все конечные компоненты, которые находятся на самом "дне" требуют передачи им callback. Тогда, чтобы в корневом "умном" компоненте назначить обработчики этим событиям, придется пробросить через props очень много всего.

И, допустим, мы отказались от какого-то конечного компонента, тогда придется модифицировать и все вышележащие, удаляя у них props, требующиеся удаленному компоненту.

Есть ли какой-то прием, позволящий этого избежать - пробрасывания в глубь множества props?

```js
const SaveButton = ({onClick}) => {return <button> .... etc}

const Panel = ({onSave, onLoad, .... etc}) => {return <div> <SaveButton onClick={onSave} ... etc}

class App extends ...
{
  onSave = () => { ... etc}

  render () {
    return <div> <Panel onSave={onSave} ... etc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких ситуациях обычно набор параметров формируется один раз при рендере первого дочернего элемента и до N-го дочернего элемента путем проброса props как есть, без их переписывания как новый объект. Например Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
const SaveButton = (props) => {return <div>
   <AnotherOneAwesomeComponent {...props} />
   <button onClick={props.onSave} />
}

const Panel = (props) => {return <div><SaveButton {...props} /></div>}

class App extends ...
{
  onSave = () => { ... etc}
  anotherOneOnSave = () => { ... etc}
  render () {
    let props = { onSave, anotherOneOnSave }
    return <div> <Panel {...props} /></div>
  }
}
```

В таком случае при отказе от какого-то из props не нужно модифицировать всю цепочку. Достаточно модифицировать лишь переменную props в компоненте *App* выше

Comment: Спасибо. Так проще, однако, так просто уже не определить, по описанию компонента, что в него передается и откуда.
Есть штуки, которые позволяет неявным образом пробрасывать props https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tunnel

Comment: Использование подобных неявных пробросов не упрощает определение что и откуда передается в компонент. Если Ваша цель упростить - используйте prop-types в котором будет все максимально описано. Если Ваша цель не использовать явный проброс props - то Вам стоит попробовать redux, mobX и прочие Flux-фреймворки

Comment: Привязать компонент к Redux и засунуть этот "контейнер" в самый нижний уровень иерархии, тогда это лишит переносимости компонент, состоящий из таких контейнеров, придется еще и redux тащить.

Comment: В приведенном Вами примере react-tunnel используется контекст. Сами facebook настоятельно не рекомендуют использовать контекст в разработке. Да и разработчик react-tunnel этого не отрицает: *react-tunnel uses React's context feature to make provided props available to children regardless of how deep they are. While this is powerful it also can be abused and make for a nightmare to manage.* Если Вы хотите применить это в чисто Вашем проекте, то почему бы и нет. Но в коллективной разработке за такое отрывают руки. Посмотрите исходники популярных библиотек. Практически везде идет проброс ...props